# Get the last column character dynamically and pass it

Tags: excel, vba

Excel VBA: I am trying to get the last column character dynamically and pass it as last column while selecting the range for sorting. But it doesn't seem to work here is the code

```
Sub Sort_THAT_IS_NOT_CALLED_SORT_BECAUSE_THAT_IS_A_RESEVED_WORD()
    Dim lastrowcheck As Long, n1 As Long, LastRowcheck1 As Long, n2 As Long
    Dim lcol As Integer, colletter As String

    With Worksheets("MergeSheet")
        lastrowcheck = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For n1 = 2 To lastrowcheck
            If .Cells(n1, 1).Value = "FUND" Then
                .Rows(n1).Delete
            End If
        Next n1

        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MergeSheet").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MergeSheet").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
            "A2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
            xlSortNormal
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MergeSheet").Sort
            lcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            colletter = ConvertToLetter(lcol)
            .SetRange Range("A2:colletter" & lastrowcheck)
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code states you have no header row but you are starting with row 2. Can you confirm no header row?

Answer (score 0):

A recorded [Range.Sort method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) is very verbose. You can typically pare down the recorded code to a small fraction of what was recorded and end up with what is actually necessary.

```
Sub Sort_THAT_IS_NOT_CALLED_SORT_BECAUSE_THAT_IS_A_RESEVED_WORD2()
    With Worksheets("MergeSheet")
        With .Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count + (.Rows(1).Row = 1), .Columns.Count).Offset(Abs(.Rows(1).Row = 1), 0)
                .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo, _
                            DataOption:=xlSortNormal, MatchCase:=False
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```